# Yii2 How to enable default assets only in certain modules

Tags: yii2

I am using basic yii2 app, I have disabled the boostrap css and js in web.php config but i want to enable it inside the module called admin.

I tried adding like this, for component section in config.php under admin module folder, but no luck!

```
'assetManager' => [
       'bundles' => [
           'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset' => [
                'js'=> ['js/boostrap.js']
            ],
           'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset' => [
               'css' => ['css/boostrap.min.css']
           ]
        ],
    ],
```

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

In your module's `init()` method, you can **override** an **exist** asset bundle like below:

```
public function init() {
    \Yii::$app->assetManager->bundles['yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset'] = [
        'css' => ['css/bootstrap_NEW.css']
    ];
    parent::init();
}
```

In above example, we override `yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset` CSS file in our module. So, in this module, it uses `bootstrap_NEW.css` instead of its default.

Please note that, you can do this in application globally, not specially in module's `init()` method. It was just a suggestion to solve this specific case.

Answer (score 4):

You should use asset bundles to handle this, **no need to modify assetManager**.

To disable Bootstrap, simply remove it from `$depends` in `AppAsset` :

```
public $depends = [
    'yii\web\YiiAsset',
];
```

Create a `ModuleAsset` class in your module :

```
class ModuleAsset extends \yii\web\AssetBundle
{
    public $depends = [
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];
}
```

Make sure to register it in your module's views (you could use a custom layout) :

```
ModuleAsset::register($this);
```

Read more : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html